# Android: Source not found. (while trying to do the Tab Layout tutorial)

Tags: android

I'm trying to do the Tab Layout tutorial and my code crashes because of "Source not found"
on the lines :

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FavouritesActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("favourites").setIndicator("favourites",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_favourites))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and to be more specific it crashes on :

```
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_favourites)
```

I do have a class named FavouritesActivity and ic_tab_favourites.xml‬ file on res/drawable
(Eclipse even autocompletes those two...).

Any idea on what could be wrong ?

edit: I found that the code in ic_tab_favourites.xml‬ is the problem, the code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_favourites_gray"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_favourites_white" />
</selector>
```

and the problem is with the drawable resources "ic_tab_favourites_gray", "ic_tab_favourites_white".

but I don't know why, Eclipse autocompletes them when I edit the .xml file and I do have
ic_tab_favourites_gray.ico, 
ic_tab_favourites_white.ico

edit 2 : if for example I change the .xml to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_main_gray"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_main_gray" />
</selector>
```

than it works (but ofcourse I don't want ic_tab_main_gray icon for this tab...)

Comment: Try to clean project.. go to Project->clean and clean your project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you used Resources res = getResources();
 in tabs activity?

Comment: could you paste your code snippet.Also have you mentioned FavouritesActivity activity in your manifeast file.

Comment: what code do you want to see ? I think I added everything that's relavent.
I have : <activity android:name=".FavouritesActivity"></activity> in my manifest file

Comment: android not able to get these two resources can't generate id's of these two resources ,if both of them are present in your project under drawable folder then try to clean project or add these two icons in your drawable folder "ic_tab_favourites_gray", "ic_tab_favourites_white".

Comment: I did that, I also noticed that the tabs that give me that problems are the ones with an icon size that is not 72x72. do you think that is the problem ?

Comment: no that is not an problem.could you mail me that project will check & will update u. on sumant4943@gmail.com

Comment: all the relavent code is posted (it really is).
I tried swapping the names of the icon that worked with the icon that didn't work and now the tab with the icon that dindn't worked works (and the tab with the icon that worked now doesn't work).

still think that the icon itself is not the problem ?